# pywintypes.error - Using pyinstaller to create a one-file bundled executable

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Running Powershell in the same directory as:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=<my_Logo.ico> BC-USD.py
```

It always end up with the same error:

```
pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Does your code import a dll? If so, you need to tell pyinstaller to include it using the --add-binary or --add-data option:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon="icon.ico" --add-binary "current/path/to/dll/my_dll.dll; folder/to/store/dll/inside/pyinstaller/bundle"
```

http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: How can I know if my code imports a dll? I am not importing explicitly